# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un Observable<Tipo[]> de Firestore ordenado?

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript

Tengo un componente de Angular2 donde necesito imprimir en HTML todos los elementos de una colección ordenados por fecha de creación. Dentro del documento de Firestore tengo una propiedad con la fecha, es la que pienso utilizar para ordenarlos.

De esta manera guardo todos los documentos en un Observable:

```
import { Post } from '../../interfaces/usuarios';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Importo las cosas de Firebase para poder obtener los documentos.

```
export interface Post { titulo: string; contenido: string; nombre_imagen: string; }
export interface PostId extends Post { id: string; }

export class NoticiasComponent implements OnInit {

  private postCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
  posts: Observable<Post[]>;
```

Declaro las variables para almacenar los datos

```
  constructor(
    private db: AngularFirestore
  ) {
      this.postCollection = db.collection<Post>('posts');
      this.posts = this.postCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Y guardo los documentos en la variable `post`. Esta variable la utilizo en el HTML para imprimir los datos con un `ngFor`:

```
 <div *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
  <!-- Imprimir los datos de cada documento -->
 </div>
```

Pero lo imprime en orden alfabético, tomando como referencia el id del documento. Necesito ordenarlos en orden en referencia a una propiedad de mi documento:

```
{
  titulo,
  contenido,
  url_imagen,
  nombre_imagen,
  fecha,  <--------- Necesito ordenarlos con esta propiedad
  ano,
  mes,
  dia
}
```

¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?

Answer (score 1):

En la inicialización de la colección de tus datos en Firestore, agrega el criterio de ordenamiento por el campo deseado y el tipo de orden (ASC,DESC): *ref => ref.orderBy('fecha', 'ASC')*

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

```
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {

      this.postCollection = db.collection<Post>('posts', ref => ref.orderBy('fecha', 'ASC')); // puedes usar ASC o DESC
      this.posts = this.postCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      });
  }
}
```

Intenta asi. :)

Comment: Para que sea aceptada la respuesta describe como llegaste a esta solución editando la respuesta